# How to use Applescript to delete conversations whose senders contain just 4 numbers from Apple's Messages app

Tags: applescript, message, imessage

I'm using the following code from Craig Smith:

```
set chatsToKill to {}
tell application "Messages"
   set allChats to every chat
   repeat with eachChat in allChats
     set thePeeps to participants of eachChat
     repeat with oneParticipant in thePeeps
        if oneParticipant's handle contains "@" then
            if chatsToKill does not contain eachChat's id then set end of chatsToKill to eachChat's id
        end if
    end repeat
  end repeat
  repeat with deathChat in chatsToKill
        delete item 1 of (get every chat whose id = deathChat)
   end repeat
end tell
```

I was wondering if there is a way to erase conversations from senders that only have 4 digits in their user handle?

The 4 digits always vary and are not the same. I tried various wildcard characters but I find that Applescript doesn't support them.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses a regular expression. If there is no match an error is thrown which is ignored

```
set chatsToKill to {}
tell application "Messages"
    set allChats to every chat
    repeat with eachChat in allChats
        set thePeeps to participants of eachChat
        repeat with oneParticipant in thePeeps
            set theHandle to handle of oneParticipant
            try
                do shell script "echo " & quoted form of theHandle & " | egrep ^[0-9]{4}$"
                if chatsToKill does not contain eachChat's id then set end of chatsToKill to eachChat's id
            end try
        end repeat
    end repeat
    repeat with deathChat in chatsToKill
        delete item 1 of (get every chat whose id = deathChat)
    end repeat
end tell
```